# error: variable 'size_map' has initializer but incomplete type

Tags: c, esp8266

Trying to compile this code with new esp-open-rtos (esp8266 sdk) but seeing error

> ```
> app_main.c:446:10: error: variable 'size_map' has initializer but incomplete type
>  enum flash_size_map size_map = system_get_flash_size_map();
> ```

```
uint32_t user_rf_cal_sector_set(void) {
enum flash_size_map size_map = system_get_flash_size_map();
uint32_t rf_cal_sec = 0;

switch (size_map) {
    case FLASH_SIZE_4M_MAP_256_256:
        rf_cal_sec = 128 - 5;
        break;

    case FLASH_SIZE_8M_MAP_512_512:
        rf_cal_sec = 256 - 5;
        break;

    case FLASH_SIZE_16M_MAP_512_512:
    case FLASH_SIZE_16M_MAP_1024_1024:
        rf_cal_sec = 512 - 5;
        break;

    case FLASH_SIZE_32M_MAP_512_512:
    case FLASH_SIZE_32M_MAP_1024_1024:
        rf_cal_sec = 1024 - 5;
        break;

    default:
        rf_cal_sec = 0;
        break;
}   

return rf_cal_sec;
```

}

tried with flash_size_map size_map = system_get_flash_size_map();
but seeing this:

> ```
> src/app_main.c:446:5: error: unknown type name 'flash_size_map'
>  flash_size_map size_map = system_get_flash_size_map();
>  ^
> ```

Comment: @B Jackson Use the type int instead of the enumeration type. Or include the definition of the enumeration before this function definition. The compiler does not see the definition of the enumeration.

Comment: Have you included the header file where the `flash_size_map` enumeration is defined?

Comment: Have you found a fix for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Such an error happens when the proper include file is not provided.

Note that having enum forward declaration is not enough - you have to have proper definition of the type.

See [an example on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/jrtPE8) - if you uncomment line 9 compilation will succeed.

With respect to your application you will need to #include <[esp_system.h](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/blob/ee0c4459d6d083cfb9da1ae39e4064c7e9dbf3cd/components/esp8266/include/esp_system.h#L204)>